# Ajax loading gif appending during calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I have this ajax call:

```
$('.ajaxtrigger2').click(function(){
$('#target').load('xxx.html');
...
```

how to append a Loading msg or image during this simple call? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another element, e.g.

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

then show the loading element when you start loading, and hide it when its done through the `load` callback.

```
$('.ajaxtrigger2').click(function() {
    $("#loading").show();
    $("target").load('xxx.html', function() { 
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Img, make the id equal to something like 'loading' and has a default style like "display: none;" and then add this to your jQuery onReady event

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () { $(this).show(); }).ajaxStop(function () { $(this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use css, and add remove stuffs.

```
<style>
 #target.loading {background image you want, alongside some greying or whatever}
</style>
<script>
....
$('.ajaxtrigger2').click(function(event){
$('#target').addClass("loading");
$('#target').load('xxx.html', function(data,text,xhr){
    $('#target').removeClass("loading");
});
});
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of ways. My preferred way is to attach a function to the ajaxStart/Stop events on the element itself.

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

The ajaxStart/Stop functions will fire whenever you do any ajax calls.